# Python Regex Sub with Multiple Patterns

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match multiple patterns using regex sub grouping and replace the match with an asterisk for a data file that has similar format to the string below. However, I am getting only the desired results for the first match.  The subsequent matches are consuming string that I did not expect.  Is there a better approach to getting the desired output below?

```
    import re
    myString = '-fruit apple -number    123 -animal  cat  -name     bob'

    match = re.compile('(-fruit\s+)(\w+)|'
                       '(-animal\s+)(cat)|'
                       '(-name\s+)(bob)')
    print(match.sub('\g<1>*', myString))
```

Current Output:

```
-fruit * -number    123 *  *
```

Desired Output:

```
-fruit * -number    123 -animal  *  -name     *
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternation does not reset the group numbers, thus your groups are numbered like `(1)(2)|(3)(4)|(5)(6)` but you do only reinsert group 1 - but should do so for groups 3 and 5 too. As non-matched groups are treated as empty string when replacing, you can simply add them to your pattern like `\g<1>\g<2>\g<3>*`.

On a sidenote I would recommend using raw strings when working with regex patterns (`r'pattern'`), so you do not have to wonder where to double backslash (e.g. `\\b`).

Comment: That worked supberb! Thanks for the explanation and the raw string tip!

Comment: "Alternation does not reset the group numbers". Thank you for a clear and concise explanation.

Comment: "Alternation does not reset the group numbers". You can 'visualize' it: print(match.findall(myString))