# How to replace multiple substrings in a filename while iterating through a folder

Tags: python-3.x, loops, replace, substring

Suppose I have a directory with a variable name called `main_dir`. In this folder I have multiple files, including `Revised Workshop FINAL.docx`, `R1 Big Presentation. July 23, 2020.pptx`, and `Results. NEW - R1 Presentation. July 28, 2020.pdf`. There are more files, but the main thing I want to do is iterate through my `main_dir` folder, look at each filename and if it contains subtrings from a list (`bad_list = [" ", ".", "-", "&", ",", "___", "__"]`), I want to replace that substring with `"_"`. I am trying to write a quick function to do this but its harder than it first seemed. This is what I've got so far:

```py
def filename_replacer(file_name):
    bad_list = [".", "-", "&", ",", "___", "__"]
    new_name = file_name.replace(" ", "_")
    for item in bad_list:
        new_name = new_name.replace(item, "_")
        
    return new_name
```

I would then apply it as I iterate through the directory as such:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(new_dir_path):
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
        new_name = filename_replacer(filename)
        os.rename(filename,new_name)
```

This works, but it is not an ideal solution; is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Regex Sub with Multiple Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606032/python-regex-sub-with-multiple-patterns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using Regex?
Python has a regex package called 're'.

```
import re

def filename_replacer(file_name):
    # Replace .-&, with _ (will convert "test&-.,123" to "test____123" )
    new_name = re.sub( "[\.\-&,_]", "_", file_name )
    
    # Replace 2+ '_' with 1 '_' (will convert "test____123" to "test_123" )
    new_name = re.sub( "[_]{2,}", "_", new_name )
    # Comment this out if you don't want multiple underscores to be replaced by a single underscore
        
    return new_name
```

Comment: That works well. Thanks for the suggestion on using the `re` module.